# Парсинг HTML без классов и ID

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php, dom, синтаксический-анализ

http://www.alib.ru/findp.php4

Вводим данные
Автор: Кузнецова Е. М. и др.
Название: Физическая химия в  вопросах и ответах
Год от: 1981
Год до: 1981

Получаем результат в браузере (в моём случае - через curl)

Вопрос:
Каким способом отпарсить и вытащить из всего текста

```
- Продавец (самый первый результат)
- Цена (Первый результат)
```

(Через DOM не получилось - т.к. отсутствую id или class)

UDP:

```
preg_match_all('/Продавец: <a href="([^"]*?)">([^<]*)<\/a>,\040(.*?)\.\)\040Цена:\040([\d]+)/ms',$string,$m);
```

Comment: XPath тебе в помощ

Comment: для xpath документ должен быть валидным xml, тут врядли...

Answer (score 1):

Похоже что структура для результатов фиксированная, тогда так:

```
{"URL продавца": 
   document
     .querySelectorAll('font p')[2]
     .childNodes[4]
     .getAttribute('href'),
 "Цена": 
   document
     .querySelectorAll('font p')[2]
     .childNodes[5].textContent
     .match(/: (.+) руб/)[1]
}
```

Понятно, что нужны доп проверки. 
Понятно, что если что изменится, то парсер сломается.
Понятно, что web service нет и не дадут, да?

ЗЫ через dom парсер аналогично, это вариант на javascript'е. проверил, вроде работает...

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_math("|Цена: (\d+) руб\.|", $txt, $m);
printr($m);
```